# A singular integral of several functions

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-analysis

While playing with some PDE I came across a singular integral that looks something like
$$T(f_1,f_2,\ldots,f_n)(x)=p.v.\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{(f_1(x)-f_1(y))(f_2(x)-f_2(y))\cdots(f_n(x)-f_n(y))}{(x-y)^n}dy$$
where the functions are really nice, say Schwartz. Clearly if $n=1$ then $T$ is just a multiple of the Hilbert transform. Therefore I'm hoping one could write this as some kind of combination of $n$ Hilbert transforms, but I don't see how. The closest thing I've found is the Calderon commutators which differ in that there are $n+1$ factors of $(x-y)$ in the denominator. In that case, Coifman, McIntosh, Meyer were able to write it in terms of $H$ (except they did it in French).

Note: I posted this question on stackexchange first but no one had an answer.

Comment: Previous post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1726814/a-hilbert-transform-that-takes-several-functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without loss of generality, $x=0$. 
Since $T(f_1,\dots,f_n)$ is $n$-linear in $(f_1,\dots,f_n)$, you can express each $f_i$ as a mixture of harmonics $\exp(it\cdot)$, $t\in\mathbb R$ (with, in general, complex coefficients), so that $T(f_1,\dots,f_n)$ is expressed as a mixture of the values $T(\exp(it_1\cdot),\dots,\exp(it_n\cdot))$ with real $t_1,\dots,t_n$. 
In turn, to express $T(\exp(it_1\cdot),\dots,\exp(it_n\cdot))$, you can expand the product $\prod_{j=1}^n(e^{it_jx}-e^{it_jy})=\prod_{j=1}^n(1-e^{it_jy})$ in the numerator of the integrand in $T(\exp(it_1\cdot),\dots,\exp(it_n\cdot))$ and then proceed as in Appendix A in https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.07365, based on Lemma A.1 there (cf. Proposition A.4 there).

**Addendum:** 
What **[[Coifman et al.](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2007065?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)]** seem to be doing concerning their formula (12) and what can be done in your situation seems really simple, much simpler than what was suggested above. For further simplicity, assume that $n=2$. Up to a constant factor, the Hilbert transform $H$ of a smooth enough function $g$ (say with a compact support) is given by the formula 
$$(Hg)(x)=\int\frac{g(x+t)-g(x)}t\,dt$$
for real $x$; the integrals here are over $\mathbb R$ and understood in the principal value sense. So, differentiating in $x$ and then integrating by parts in $t$, one has 
$$(Hg)'(x)=\int\frac{g'(x+t)-g'(x)}t\,dt
=\int\frac{g(x+t)-g(x)-g'(x)t}{t^2}\,dt.$$
Letting now $g(y):=(f_1(y)-f_1(0))(f_2(y)-f_2(0))$, one has $g(0)=g'(0)=0$, whence 
$$T(f_1,f_2)(0)=(Hg)'(0).$$
The general case of any natural $n$ is similar.

Comment: I see, that seems to work. I'm still wondering though if you can write it in terms of Hilbert transforms.

Comment: Do you mean like formula (12) in Coifman et al.? There you need to differentiate an approximate $\epsilon$-Hilbert transform $n$ times and then let $\epsilon\to0$.

Comment: That's the one. Maybe I can write this integral in that form.

Comment: I have added an explanation of how to express $T(f_1,\dots,f_n)$ in terms of the $(n-1)$th derivative of the Hilbert transform.

Comment: The addendum looks like what I was hoping for, thanks!

Comment: For $n$ functions one can write $H(f_1,\ldots,f_n)=\frac{i^n}{n!}D_y^{n-1}sgn(D_y)\prod_{i=1}^n(f_i(x)-f_i(y))$.